# Foreign Key to a table with 2 columns primary key (CompositeId)

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, foreign-keys, primary-key

I've defined the primary key as following:

```
CompositeId()
    .KeyProperty(x => x.Id)
    .KeyProperty(x => x.Type);
```

I've tried the following:

```
References(x => x.EntityWith2ColsPK);
```

And failed with:

> Foreign key (Fk_MyEntity_EntityWith2ColsPK:MyEntities [Fk_EntityWith2ColsPK])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (EntityWith2ColsPKs [Id, Type])

How can I reference EntityWith2ColsPK from another entity?

---

**Update:**

I've tried the following (according to AlfeG's comment):

```
HasMany<EntityWith2ColsPK>(x => x.EntityWith2ColsPK).KeyColumns.Add("Id", "Type").Cascade.All();
```

Which failed with:

> Custom type does not implement UserCollectionType: EntityWith2ColsPK

But anyway I don't want a 1 to many relation, I want a 1 to 1 relation. Still, I can't make either of them work.

Also, I've tried:

```
HasOne<EntityWith2ColsPK>(x => x.EntityWith2ColsPK).PropertyRef(x => x.Id).PropertyRef(x => x.Type);
```

Which fails with:

> NHibernate.MappingException : property not found: Type on entity EntityWith2ColsPK

What can I do for this to really work?

---

I managed to achieve something in the db.. but yet, for some reason I suspect it maps the property "Type" twice, because I want it to be both part of the Primary Key, and part of the Foreign Key..
This is what I did:

```
References(x => x.EntityWith2ColsPK).Columns("EntityWith2ColsPKId", "Type").Formula("Id = :EntityWith2ColsPKId AND Type = :Type");
```

But I received the following exception:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException : Invalid index 8 for this SqlParameterCollection with Count=8.

Because the mapping of this entity is same as EntityWith2ColsPK:

```
CompositeId()
    .KeyProperty(x => x.Id)
    .KeyProperty(x => ((ILocalizedEntity) x).Language);
```

HELP!

Comment: It's duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460648/how-to-map-composite-primary-key-to-foreign-in-fluent-nhibernate so You can find anser by this link

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this since you aren't using cascade anyway on your `Reference`

```
References(x => x.EntityWith2ColsPK)
    .Columns(new string[] { "ID", "TYPE" })
    .Not.Update()
    .Not.Insert();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I've spent the entire weekend trying to research this, with no success.. I'm positive I've tried what you gave me and while changing other things at the same time it failed.. Now it works :) Thanks again.

Comment: You may want to change the column names in the database (if you can) to something other than id and type.  For example in a table called `order` you would have a column called `order_id`.

Comment: I'm having problem with that... because I want "OrderID" to be updated and inserted but Type not to be mapped again (because Type is already part of the CompositeId), so it's still not solved yet

Comment: I've tried the following:

`References(memberExpression)
    .Columns("CategoryId")
    .Nullable()
    .Columns("Language")
    .Not.Update()
    .Not.Insert();`

But it applies, not insert & not update on both columns